# Accidentally created two teams

Tags: bug, status-completed, old-teams

I'm not at all sure how I managed it, but I created two teams for graze.

- https://stackoverflow.com/teams/172/graze
- https://stackoverflow.com/teams/171/graze

I've deleted 171.

I didn't think there was anything that unusual about how I was going about setting up the team.

Comment: Accidentally double-clicked the "submit" button?

Comment: Yeah, looks like double-clicking results in two Teams. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 6):

A change for disabling the submit button after click has been pushed and will go live after the next build.